# IOException when trying to read http connection response

Tags: java, http, ioexception

I'm submitting the request below in `Java` via a `Websphere Portlet`.
It works fine when I submit manually using `postman` (chrome extension) but cannot get it to succeed via `java`.
What am I missing?

I imported the SSL cert from remote host into `Websphere`, so SSL connections are not the issue.
Exception in logs ..

```
[7/15/14 23:06:39:993 BST] 00000170 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service CWSRV0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause MyApp: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://server.com/msg
```

This is the `java` code invoking the request and trying to read the response ..

```
URL url = new URL("https://server.com/msg");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

String body = URLEncoder.encode("{\"x\": \"hello\"}", "UTF-8");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(body);
out.close();

// Exception occurs here ..
BufferedReader rd2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

while ((line = rd2.readLine()) != null) {
    result += line;
}
rd2.close();
```

Comment: HTTP 500 error indicates server-side error. I think you need to take a look at the server side code.

Comment: You need to take a look at the server-side *logs.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solution, to not `URLEncoder.encode()` the `POST` body ..

```
URL url = new URL(queries.getQuery(sessionBean.getSelectedQuery()));
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

String json = "{\"x\": \"hello\"}";

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(json);
out.close();

BufferedReader rd2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

while ((line = rd2.readLine()) != null) {
    result += line;
}
rd2.close();
```